# MongoDb aggregate query in java with mod

Tags: java, mongodb

Hello i run this command in my shell:

```
db.getCollection('unaProva').aggregate( [ { 
$group : { _id : "$groupValue" ,total:{$sum:"$weight"}} }, { 
$project : { _id:0,groupValue : "$_id" , total : "$total" ,     
remainder: { $mod: [ "$total", "$_id" ] } } }] )
```

I works but i need that it works in my Java code and I don't know how can I convert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't check this code because I don't have the collection, but it should be something like this:

```
BasicDBList modArgs = new BasicDBList();
modArgs.add("$total");
modArgs.add("$_id");
coll.aggregate(asList(
    group("$groupValue", sum("total", "$weight")),
    project(fields(computed("groupValue", "$_id"),
        include("total"), excludeId(), 
        computed("remainder", new BasicDBObject("$mod", modArgs))))
));
```

Note that I'm using a bunch of static imports:

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators.sum;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.group;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.project;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.computed;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.excludeId;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.fields;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.include;
```